# JS: Разбить длинную строку на определенные участки

Tags: javascript

Есть текст. Его нужно разбить на несколько частей до пробела или точки/запятой. Так же эта строка не должны быть длинее определенного

К примеру:

Текст нужно разбить на 3 куска.

1-я часть максимальная длина 20 символов

2-я часть максимальная длина 40 символов и это продолжение первой части

3-я часть максимальная длина 50 символов и это продолжение второй части

Comment: Вы бы пример текста привели и того, что ожидается. На вскидку: `txt = '...'; re = /((([^ \.;]{1,20})[^ \.;]{1,20})[^ \.;]{1,10})/; console.log(txt.match(re));` Второй элемент вернет 3 часть, третий элемент вернет 2 часть, а четвертый элемент - 1 часть

Comment: Ой, я там перепутал немного. Мне че-то показалось, что 3 часть включает в себя вторую, а вторая - первую. Если включать не надо, то сама регулярка немного меняется: `re = /([^ \.;]{1,20})([^ \.;]{1,40})([^ \.;]{1,50})/;` Ну и с частями я там напутал, первая часть - второй элемент, вторая часть - третий элемент, а третья часть - четвертый элемент. Только надо учитывать, что для строки `123` по вашему описанию подходит разбиение на части как `[1]`, `[2]` и `[3]`, поэтому и регулярка так же это воспримет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте такой вариант https://jsfiddle.net/h8k0t6e9/

```js
var text = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";

var blocks = [20, 40, 50];
var ps = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
var lastSpace = 0;
var beginString = 0;
var endString = 0;

blocks.forEach(function(block, i) {
  endString += block;

  lastSpace = Math.max(
    text.lastIndexOf(' ', endString),
    text.lastIndexOf('.', endString),
    text.lastIndexOf(',', endString)
  );
  ps[i].innerText = text.substring(beginString, lastSpace);
  beginString = lastSpace + 1;

});
```

```html
<p id="v1"></p>
<p id="v2"></p>
<p id="v3"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Результат выполнения смотрите в консоли (Например инструменты разработчика Chorme) или замените вызовы console.log на alert.

```js
var text = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";

var parts = [20, 40, 50];
var begin = 0;
for (i in parts) {
  var part = parts[i];

  var subStr = text.substring(begin, part + begin);
  begin = part;
  var last = subStr.lastIndexOf(";");
  if (last < 0) last = subStr.lastIndexOf(" ");
  console.log(subStr, " ", last);

  subStr = subStr.substring(0, last);
  console.log(subStr);
}
```

Comment: Lorem Ipsum is simpl   14
js:27 Lorem Ipsum is
js:24 y dummy text of the printing and typeset   32
js:27 y dummy text of the printing and
js:24 printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has   46
js:27 printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum

Comment: Не совсем так. Слово не должно обрываться.

Comment: Закомментируйте первый console.log. Во втором фраза заканчивается на последнем пробеле или ";".

Comment: Надо заканчивать не последним пробелом, а первым. Т.е. полученный текст не должен содержать никаких пробелов. Если бы @LevMalinovski привел пример текста и того, что ожидается, было бы проще. Например, по его описанию строку `123` надо разбить на три массива `[1], [2], [3]`, но сомневаюсь что это именно то, что требуется

Comment: Если первым то вызовы lastIndexOf нужно заменить на indexOf

Answer (score 0):

Все просто чертовски: заменяешь в исходной строке регуляркой точку с запятой на "пробел+точка_с_запятой+пробел", потом сплитишь строку по пробелам в массив, из получившегося массива набиваешь строки-куски нужного размера.

Вот сплит:
http://javascript.ru/String/split

Вот реплейс по регулярке :
http://javascript.ru/String/replace

Вот регулярка (точнее, уже кусок кода):

```
sourceText.replace(/[\;]{1}/g,' ; ')
```

Остальной код - банально простой.